# When couples only have children until the first boy is born, what it the ratio of sexes?

Tags: probability, independence

For one of my homework, I was given this question.

Married couples in a community only have children until the first boy is born (we neglect cases of twins).
What is the ratio of sexes in this community? How is it about independence of sexes of children?

So for the first part, I expected it to be a 1:1 ratio which was correct but for the second part, I don't really understand the second part but I thought it will be independent.

Here is the answer given:
But children within a family are not anymore independent as the youngest child is always a boy and his siblings, if any, are always girls.

Surely the events are still independent? Why does being in a family change that...

Edit: Sorry, I dont see why this is a duplicate. The first part of the question which is identical about the expectation being 1/2, I already knew. It is the second part that I'm stuck at and interested in. (It doesn't talk about multiple generations in this question like it does in the duplicate.)

Comment: I don't see why this is marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what two events are involved in the question of independence?